# Gradle: Adding Dependencies

Tags: java, jsp, gradle

I'm working on a JSP project and I want to add Apache FileUpload library. What is the best way to to do it? 
Adding the the .jars (commons-io / fileupload) in the dependencies or by copy-pasting the source files? 
In the first option, how can I do that?

in build.gradle, the dependencies are like this:

```
dependencies {
staticAnalysis  "com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle:${checkstyleVersion}",
                "net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd-java:${pmdVersion}",
                "com.google.code.findbugs:findbugs:${findbugsVersion}",
                "de.andrena.tools.macker:macker:1.0.1"

appengineSdk    "com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:${appengineVersion}"

compile         "com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.4.4",
                "com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:${appengineVersion}",
                "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0",
                "com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer:owasp-java-html-sanitizer:20160924.1",
                "com.mailjet:mailjet-client:4.0.5",
                "com.sendgrid:sendgrid-java:2.2.2",
                "com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:1.19.3",
                "com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.19.3",
                "com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:1.19.3",
                "joda-time:joda-time:2.9.7",
                "org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-impl:1.2.5",
                "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't intend to make any changes in the source code, I don't suggest you to add source files in your project. Still if you want to make some changes; do it by overriding the original methods in your project, not changing the original codes.

One of the mayor advantages of Gradle is the dependency logic. By using dependencies you have the ability of upgrading the whole work easyly and get rid of all the jar file downloading and integrating work.

You can find most of the open-source tools in online repository portals like https://mvnrepository.com.

Apache Fileupload repository page is: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload.

Chose the version which you want and get the dependency code for Gradle like this one:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload
compile group: 'commons-fileupload', name: 'commons-fileupload', version: '1.3.2'
```

You will see this is the best practise with less work and most efficient way when upgrading.

Answer (score 2):

just add the following lines to the gradle file in the compile section.

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload
compile group: 'commons-fileupload', name: 'commons-fileupload', version: '1.3'
```

link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3